# Find row via As Of date in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with the following structure (showing sample data for one employee):

```
Employee    Date        PayRate
--------------------------------
123         1/1/2015    15.00
123         1/1/2014    14.50
123         1/1/2013    14.00
```

I need to be able to use an "As Of" date to select the pay rate given any given date.  So if I pass in emp# 123 and 1/5/2014, I should get $14.50.  If I pass in emp# 123 and 7/8/2013, I should get $14.00 and if I use emp# 123 and today's date, I should get $15.00 and so on.

I know how to do this in pure SQL, but I'm stuck at an approach for doing this in a pure System.Data.DataTable.  I have been out of development for a while, and never did learn to use LINQ (and I suspect it's easy to do in LINQ).

I thought of the approach of looping through the table until I find the first record with a date less than my "As-of" date matching the employee# but that seems like a very inelegant way to handle this.

I also thought of using

```
DataTable.Select("Date > #" + AsOfDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#", "AsOfDate");
```

to get a DataRow[] array, and selecting the first value if it returns more than zero rows, but that also seems like a hack.

What is the standard/best practice/recommended approach to this these days?

If it matters, I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: You could always just query the datatable, something like this:

var res = (from row in myDTable.AsEnumerable()
where row.Field<DateTime>("Date") < DateTIme.Today
orderby row.Field<DateTime>("Date") descending select row).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

That should give you the row containing the PayRate you want.  Pseudo-code, not tested at all.

Comment: I am taking that and modifying it now.  I know this is a dumb question, but is that LINQ, or something else? Just so I know what to go learn, now that I'm trying to develop again.

Comment: Yes, this is a LINQ query.  You should really dig into that, LINQ is a powerful stuff :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the rows by date in descending order and find the first one of which the data is smaller than the reference date:

```
DataTable.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Employee") == 123)
         .OrderByDescending (r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
         .FirstOrDefault (r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date") < new DateTime(2013, 7, 8) )
```